# Incremental (on-the-fly) smooth trajectory interpolation algorithm from waypoints?

Tags: control, motion-planning, algorithm

short version (TL;DR):

I'm receiving x(t) waypoints "online", which I must travel through at the specified times. I need an algorithm that would plan a **smooth** trajectory in-between them **without knowing the whole trajectory in advance**.

Longer version:

I have a 1D motion control problem. I control a DOF of a robot, and a primary design goal is for the motion to be very smooth.

A high-level controller (computer) sends my low-level motion controller a waypoint, expressed as an (x<sub>i</sub>, t<sub>i</sub>) pair, every N msec. I am running my control loop at a much higher rate, say every 1 msec.

Because of various constraints, I am not able to get the whole trajectory in advance - **I am getting new waypoints as the robot is moving through previous waypoints**. I am, however, able to receive a few waypoints in advance (say 3 or 4) so I have a short buffer (look-ahead) and not limited to working strictly with the next waypoint only.

I need an algorithm that would build a **smooth** trajectory in between these waypoints. 'Smooth' here means continuous velocity and continuous acceleration (which also implies bounded jerk).

I have tried to implement a **cubic spline interpolation** scheme, since it appears to be exactly what my problem requires: a piecewise function of 3rd degree polynomials, which are guaranteed to have continuous first and second derivatives everywhere, including at the 'stitches'. However, all the implementations I saw generate the spline based on *all* the data points, which unlike my case, are usually known in advance. My attempts to implement *incremental* spline generation have failed, and I'm starting to figure this is not a technical error but a mathematical impossibility. If you ask, I'll edit and try to formally explain why I think so, but this question is already quite long as it is.

So, for concrete questions:

- Do you know if it's possible to build a cubic spline this way, incrementally, and keep its 1st and 2nd derivatives smooth?
- If, as I suspect, it's impossible: What other algorithm would you suggest, that will build the trajectory incrementally, pass through all the waypoints at the specified times, while keeping everything smooth up to the 2nd derivative? Alternatively, have I defined a problem with no solution and I must relax some of the requirements?

Thank you!

Comment: What if you assume 3 or 4 more waypoints past the known waypoints? This won't work in all scenarios. However, if you imagine a straight line trajectory as a baseline scenario, it is easy to project the line of travel several way points ahead. Curves and zig-zag motions wouldn't be as safe to project out very far, but you could build in shorter distances for them. The catch would be illogical waypoints which were in a totally different direction than the device was traveling. Those situations seem to fit your assumption of mathematical impossibility.

Comment: you named the buffer correctly look-ahead. Have you looked at CNC Look-Ahead algorithms?

Comment: Is there something which prohibits you to start planning from the next waypoint you will reach and iterate? I mean not keeping the past but only making cubic spline from the current state to the waypoints you have at the moment, and re-compute cubic spline when you get new waypoint, either from current state or next waypoint?

Comment: @takintoolong: I do have available a few waypoints into the future. The question was, essentially, how to use them in order to interpolate *in between* those waypoints, while getting continuous position, velocity and acceleration. If I understand your comment correctly, you discuss extrapolation rather than interpolation.

Comment: @50k4: I did not, I'll see what I can find, thanks.

Comment: @N.Staub - doing what you say, I don't think I'll meet the requirement of continuous first and second derivatives (i.e. velocity and acceleration). If you do have an algorithm that will do what you say and meet these continuity constraints, please share!

Comment: I  think that if you use the current state as the first point in your spline it should give you a smooth trajectory from your current point to the next waypoints. Using the full current state guarantees that the higher derivatives are continuous.

Comment: @Tinkerer I was thinking you might implement some sort of predictive element beyond the stated few waypoints into the future, as a work around.